# AngularJS - ngGrid not displaying correct page size & pagination not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

So, I am trying to implement ngGrid data pagination on some data I get from a service.  I get the table to display and the search filter works.  In my pagingOptions I specify the pageSize as 25, however the table displays all of my data.  Another problem I am having is when I click on the pagination buttons, the page turns and goes to the next data, however when I get to page 3/6 or so, my data is deleted and the pagination switches to saying page 3/1.  Please help, code below:

```
var drilldownDirective = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            tableData: '=',
            numPages: '@'
        },
        controller: function($rootScope, $scope, DashboardFactory) {
            var tableData = $scope.tableData;
            var dashboardreportid = tableData.dashboardreportid;
            var companyid = tableData.companyid;
            var companybrandid = tableData.companybrandid;
            var startdate = tableData.startdate;
            var enddate = tableData.enddate;
            var clientdb = tableData.clientdb;
            var calltype = tableData.calltype;
            var secondarycallval = tableData.secondarycallval;
            $scope.gridData = [];

            var onSuccess = function(response) {
                var d, t, dt, dtobj, obj;
                $scope.repdata = [];
                $scope.titles = [];

                for (d in response.repdata) {
                    var dtArray = {};

                    obj = response.repdata[d];
                    $scope.repdata.push(obj);

                    for (var d in obj.data) {
                        var fieldName = d.split(" ").join("_");
                        var val = obj.data[d];
                        dtArray[fieldName] = val;
                    }

                    //push new created object to gridData array
                    $scope.gridData.push(dtArray);
                }
            };

            var onError = function(response) {
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
            };

            DashboardFactory.getDashboardReportData(dashboardreportid, companyid, companybrandid, startdate, enddate, clientdb, calltype, secondarycallval).then(onSuccess, onError);

            //ngGrid options
            $scope.filterOptions = {
                filterText: "",
                useExternalFilter: true
            }; 

            $scope.totalServerItems = 0;
            $scope.pagingOptions = {
                pageSizes: [10, 25, 50, 100],
                pageSize: 25,
                currentPage: 1
            };  

            $scope.getPagedDataAsync = function (pageSize, page, searchText) {
                setTimeout(function () {    
                    if (searchText) {};
                    $scope.setPagingData($scope.gridData, page, pageSize);
                }, 100);
            };

            $scope.setPagingData = function(data, page, pageSize){ 
                var pagedData = data.slice((page - 1) * pageSize, page * pageSize);
                $scope.gridData = pagedData;
                $scope.totalServerItems = data.length;
                if (!$scope.$$phase) {
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            };

            $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage);

            $scope.$watch('pagingOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal !== oldVal && newVal.currentPage !== oldVal.currentPage) {
                    $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
                }
            }, true);

            $scope.$watch('filterOptions', function (newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                  $scope.getPagedDataAsync($scope.pagingOptions.pageSize, $scope.pagingOptions.currentPage, $scope.filterOptions.filterText);
                }
            }, true);                

            $scope.gridOptions = {
                data: 'gridData',
                showFilter: true,
                enablePaging: true,
                totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
                pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
                plugins: [new ngGridCsvExportPlugin(), new ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin()],
                showFooter: true,
                jqueryUITheme: true,
                filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions
            };
        },
        templateUrl: "dashboard/drilldownTable.html",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you find ngGrid not working correctly, try to doing the same thing with ngTasty http://zizzamia.com/ng-tasty/#TableServerSide should be more straightforward, and if you find a problem with that I will be happy to help you.